# Numeric comparisons inside grepl in r

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison, grepl

I am trying to find unique values in col1 of my dataframe df where it is less than a specified number( for eg:- 15)

I tried the following code,

```
unique(df[grepl("increased by 1", df$col1) &
( as.numeric(grepl("[0-9]",df$col1 )) <15),]$col1)
```

But it seems only the first grepl is working.

```
[1] "increased by 17 %" "increased by 10 %" "increased by 16 %" "increased by 1 %"  "increased by 14 %"
[6] "increased by 13 %" "increased by 12 %" "increased by 15 %" "increased by 11 %" "increased by 18 %"
```

Any suggestions to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a new variable with `gsub`?

```
# get vector in R
temp <- c("increased by 17 %", "increased by 10 %", "increased by 16 %",   
          "increased by 1 %",  "increased by 14 %", "increased by 13 %", 
          "increased by 12 %", "increased by 15 %", "increased by 11 %", 
          "increased by 18 %")
# extract value as numeric
myValues <- as.numeric(gsub("increased by ([0-9]+) %", "\\1", temp))
```

To produce a logical vector

```
myValues > 15
```

To extract the values

```
myValues[myValues > 15]
```

To get the indices

```
which(myValues > 15)
```

Comment: Thanks Imo, that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

`grepl("[0-9]",df$col1)` just searches for digits inside `df$col1`, and returns `TRUE` when a digit is found. Casting a `TRUE` to numeric just yields a 1. Which is always less than 15.

So this is not really what you're looking for. As lmo mentions, you probably want to extract the actual number via something like `gsub`.